# How to work on a list in a range in a word file using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-automation, word-interop

I am trying to edit a word document using word automation. In the document, there is a list of references that I want to verify and edit one by one. I have selected the references part in a range and now I want to loop through the list.

```
object start = new Regex(@"(References)\s*:?\s*").Match(wordText).Index;
        object end = wordText.Length;

        Word.Range rngRef = doc.Range(start,end);
```

This is how I have selected range, now how do I select list and loop through the items?

Comment: `rngRef.Select();` will select the text.  `rngRef.Text` is a string which contains the selection.   BTW: If the regex fails the entire document will be selected because `start` will get the value `0`

Comment: @Luuk thanks for pointing that out, I observed it in few cases and didn't know what was happening. But how do I select and loop through the ordered list?

Comment: Don't use RegEx when finding things in Word: use Word's built-in `Find` functionality, with the **wildcard** options, if regex type of search is required. RegEx can work only on a string, so whatever is "found" has no relation to the document content. Word's `Find` functionality operates in the context of the document. `Find` can be performed in a loop. There are lots of examples here and elsewhere on the Internet...

Answer (score 0):

I depend how the ordered list is exactly 'formatted' in Word. If this is just a number of paragraphs one could do (to get the text from the paragraphs):

```
int i = 0;
var paragraphs = rngRef.Paragraphs;
foreach (Word.Paragraph item in paragraphs)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", ++i, item.Range.Text);
}
```